# Force to display only desktop version on all screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web

I want to force the desktop version to show the same on all screens. I go through with all the solution and I got the one solution:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=1920">
```

But this works fine when I open it in responsiveness mode on chrome but it doesn't work when I switch it to my screen. I have attached the screenshots and they are taken on the same dimensions.
[image]
[image]

since the first screen and second screen are of 1000px. On first screen you can see the margin of beauty button from right side but this is not same on second screen. I want the same margin on both screen
Both are same dimension so both should have same space on screen also

Comment: They look the same to me... what are the differences you think are relevant? Obviously the Responsive toolbar, ruler, grabby-resize thing, etc. are not going to be there because you're not in responsive mode.

Comment: I want the same view for all screen even the same desktop view on mobile

Comment: Again, you need to be specific about what you're seeing that you're not expecting, or what you're not seeing that you are expecting. We can't read your mind, and showing pictures and saying "See!" isn't terribly useful.

Comment: Heretic, since the first screen and second screen are of 1000px. On first screen you can see the margin of beauty button from right side but this is not same on second screen. I want the same margin on both screen

Comment: [Edit] your question with your explanation. People don't read comments.

Comment: Afaik there's no easy way for this. You can try transform scale on body but it will probably end up messy beyond repair. A proper way is to make the layout scalable by using rem everywhere